# Cannot set session user_data in codeigniter when the apps was uploaded in hosting

Tags: codeigniter, session

I have a problem in my web app, I use codeigniter 2.2.6, the app work app work fine when i run in localhost but when i was upload to web hosting, cannot set session user_data. Any one can help and discuss my problem? Thanks

```
<?php
```

defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Login extends CI_Controller {

```
function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->helper('form');
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->load->library('session');

}



public function index(){

    if ($this->session->userdata('site_lang')=="") {
            $this->session->set_userdata('site_lang','english');
    }
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username_login', 'Username', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password_login', 'Password', 'required');

    if ($this->form_validation->run()){

        //my code !
        $m_url = URL_API;
        $function = "login_user";
        $username_login = $this->input->post('username_login');
        $password_login = $this->input->post('password_login');

        $url = $m_url . "/" . $function . "?" ."u=". $username_login . "&" ."p=". md5($password_login);

        $json_data = file_get_contents($url);

        $data = json_decode($json_data);
        $status = $data->status;

        if ($data->status == "000"){

            $login= array (
            'session_username_login' => $data->username,
            'session_customer_id' => $data->customer_id,
            'session_customer_no' => $data->customer_no,
            'session_customer_name' => $data->customer_name,
            'session_customer_email' => $data->customer_email,
            'session_customer_gender' => $data->customer_gender,
            'session_customer_status' => $data->customer_status,
            'session_customer_handphone' => $data->customer_handphone,
            'session_customer_birthday' => $data->customer_birthday,
            'session_customer_address' => $data->customer_address,

            'session_password_login' => md5($password_login) );

            $this->session->set_userdata($login);
            $_SESSION['session_username_login'] = $data->username;

        }

        elseif ($status == "007") {

            $this->session->set_flashdata('msg','<div class="alert alert-danger text-center">'.lang('username_password_wrong').'</div>');
            redirect(MENU_LOGIN);
            }

        elseif ($status == "005") {

            $this->session->set_flashdata('msg','<div class="alert alert-danger text-center">'.lang('password_wrong').'</div>');
            redirect(MENU_LOGIN);
            }

        elseif ($status == "004") {

            $this->session->set_flashdata('msg','<div class="alert alert-danger text-center">'.lang('username_wrong').'</div>');
            redirect(MENU_LOGIN);
            }


    }

    if($this->session->userdata('session_password_login') != null){

        redirect(MENU_MARKETPLACE);
        exit;
    }

    }
    $this->load->view(MENU_LOGIN);
}
```

}

Comment: show your code what is not working & what you are trying

Comment: my code is working in localhost but not work (set_userdata) when was upload to web hostings

Comment: i was edited my question that show my code @RejoanulAlam

Comment: Load session library in your `autoload.php` so that session can be available entire application. secondly how can you realized that your `set_userdata` not working? more precise you question

Comment: I was load session library in autoload.php. I know from that i printed all_userdata